# Changing a list of strings to list of integers

Tags: python, list

I have a list of strings which have numbers in them and I want to redefine another list which contains the same items but now in integer form. So I wrote the following code but it is not working and only appends the last item to the numbers list. What did I do wrong?

```
numbers = "9, 223, 372, 036, 854, 775, 807"

split_numbers = numbers.split(", ")
print(split_numbers)

for number_string in split_numbers:
    numbers_list = []
    number = int(number_string)
    numbers_list.append(number)

print(numbers_list)
```

Comment: You can use `numbers_list = [int(number_string) for number_string in numbers.split(", ")]`.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal you must change `split_numbers.split(", ")` with `numbers.split(", ")`

Comment: @LoukasPap Already fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

You declare list inside the loop, so you reset it each loop.

```
numbers_list = [int(x) for x in split_numbers]
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this code is not working as expected is that you put 'numbers_list = []' line at the start of the for loop. It means that this list is created as empty in every loop interation, i.e. the program creates a list, adds a number, then makes this list empty and adds a number and so on.

Solution is pretty simple, just change the code to this:

```
numbers = "9, 223, 372, 036, 854, 775, 807"

split_numbers = numbers.split(", ")
print(split_numbers)

numbers_list = []

for number_string in split_numbers:
   number = int(number_string)
   numbers_list.append(number)

print(numbers_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
numbers = "9, 223, 372, 036, 854, 775, 807"

split_numbers = numbers.split(", ")
print(split_numbers)

# has to be outside the for loop
numbers_list = []

for number_string in split_numbers:
    number = int(number_string)
    numbers_list.append(number)

print(numbers_list)
```

Comment: Your answer contains code without explanation. It's better to include details about *how* your answer answers the question.

Comment: I am thankful for your supportive advice!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you empty the `split_numbers` list at every iteration so it only ends up with one item in it (the last one).  You need to initialize the list only once, before the loop.

Or try this:

```
*split_numbers, = map(int,numbers.split(", "))
```